# Iptables does not seem to be applying SNAT to packets sent on a raw socket

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat

I'm sending packets from a user space program to my wireless interface wlan0. I've set up a SNAT rule with iptables as follows

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.3
```

And it works for all normal traffic going out of my machine.

I am working on a program that needs to craft packets starting from layer 2.  Iptables is not applying SNAT to any layer 3 packets sent by this program.

Is there any way I can send packets in user space from layer 2 and still have NAT applied to them?

I've reposted this from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/793027/iptables-does-not-seem-to-be-applying-snat-to-packets-sent-on-a-raw-socket). Will make an update if I get anything there.

Comment: If you're working at layer 2 then a SNAT for the source IP address (layer 3) doesn't quite make sense...

Comment: I'm still using the other layers, I just need to craft packets starting at layer 2.  I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When packets are send directly on the Ethernet interface, they won't be going through the IP layer in the kernel's network stack. That means no iptables either.

You'll need to either get the program to generate the packet the way you want it to look, or you'll need to have the packet send through the IP layer in your network stack.

There are a few different ways you can get the packet through your network stack:

- Send it to the MAC address of your own machine, such that it gets routed by the kernel and then forwarded back onto the same interface.
- Send it through a virtual network interface instead of a physical interface.
- Use a socket on the IP layer instead of the Ethernet layer.

Answer (score 0):

Raw Sockets bypass the netfilter stack, so iptables will have no effect on these packets.

Comment: Is there a way to do something with packets sent through raw sockets?